# How to calculate a normalized direction of two rotations?

Tags: unity, rotation, quaternion, linear-algebra

In Vector math and translations we can do:

```
dir = (v1 - v2).norm
```

and then `v1.translate(dir * 50)` so `v1` moves to the `v2`'s direction.

What about `rotation` and `eulerAngles`?

Here's my attempt, but it doesn't work, probably from some obvious reasons.

```
Vector3 initial = ob1.transform.rotation.eulerAngles; // get it's initial rotation
ob1.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,90)); // rotate
Vector3 after = ob1.transform.rotation.eulerAngles; // store new rotation
ob1.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,-90)); // rotate back to initial

// here I need to calculate the direction so I can do rotate(dir * 50); or something similar
```

I need to get the rotation direction, so I can rotate the object continously with direction, not with a fixed desired angle value.

To be super clear, I need to get this blue line direction:

[image]

The object is initially rotated by `(0,0,57)`.
I need to rotate it around it's center (green axis).

I know I can do `logo1.transform.RotateAround(logo1.transform.position, logo1.transform.up, 80);` and it works, but I need the direction from this, so I can use it in Tweening.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of code that will do the trick:

```
Vector3 AxisBetween(Quaternion start, Quaternion end) {
    // Here we form a rotation that "undoes" the start orientation,
    // then applies the end orientation on top.
    Quaternion travel = end * Quaternion.Inverse(start);

    // By construction: end = (travel * start)
    // So travel serves as the "quaternion difference" between the two.

    // Now we just extract its axis of rotation.
    Vector3 axis;
    float angle;    
    travel.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);

    // I can't recall what the range of these angles is, so this might not be required:
    if(angle < 0f)
        axis *= -1f;

    return axis;
}
```

Note that if `start` = `end` you'll get an axis full of infinities back, since a zero degree rotation around any & every axis maps `start` to `end`. ;) So be sure to check for infinities before using.